# Does try? Data(contentsOf: URL) use caching?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection

I'm seeing an issue where I'm running the below multiple times with different URLs, and I'm getting the same data back 'sometimes' (it seems random). I'm wondering if iOS is caching some pages and giving me back the same data and not actually going to the URL.

Is there a cache? If so, is there a way to clear it before each call?

```
if let dataString = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) {
    let pageContent = String(data: dataString, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
}
```

Comment: Anyway you are strongly discouraged from loading data from a remote URL with synchronous `Data(contentsOf`.

Comment: I'm doing it from a background thread, What else should I be doing?

Comment: `URLSession` as suggested in the answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at [init(contentsOf:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1407864-init) which provides an option called `NSData.ReadingUncached`.  That's evidence that the simple form is cached and an answer to how you can control whether its cached.

A better approach with even more control is via [URLSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession)

Answer (score 0):

There are some cached files in the cache directory - print `FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!`

After loading an image from a remote url, I added an extension `.jpg` to the cached file name. And I could see the image.